# XSL FO - Detect char and replace

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

Sample XML:

```
<Title>Test Δ Test</Title>
```

This what I have in my XSL:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Title"/>
```

I need to write a template that will match the Delta char (for example) and replace the symbol with: `<fo:inline font-family="Symbol">Δ</fo:inline>`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can specify multiple font families in the `font-family` property value. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-family)  Does the problem go away if you just add "`, Symbol`" to whatever `font-family` value that applies to `Title`?

Comment: I didn't know you can do that. So simple. I used font-family="Helvetica,Symbol" and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your template template Title, you can add this code to detect the delta entity:

```
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="&#916;">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <fo:inline font-family="Symbol"><xsl:text>&#916;</xsl:text</fo:inline>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
```